# Functional Sieve of Eratosthenes in Clojure

Tags: performance, clojure, sieve-of-eratosthenes

For some reason, this is the first time I've ever written an implementation of the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). I basically just stared at the Wikipedia walkthrough of the algorithm until it made sense, then tried making the algorithm in idiomatic Clojure.

I'm not using an boolean array representing every number. Instead, I have a `marked` set, and a `primes` vector that are maintained separately.

- My main concern is performance. I was hoping for better performance than I'm getting. It's only about 2x faster than the naïve implementation (included below the Sieve code for reference). I'd mainly like recommendations for speeding this up.
- I decided to go overboard with the use of `->>` here. It just fit so perfectly everywhere, but I think I may have taken it too far.
- Is there a way to avoid the `cond` dispatch in `naïve-prime?`?
- Anything else notable.

---

```
(ns irrelevant.sieves.eratosthenes)

; ----- Sieve -----

(defn sieve-primes [n]
  (loop [p 2 ; First prime
         marked #{} ; Found composites
         primes []]
    (let [mults (->> n
                     (range p)
                     (map #(* p %))
                     (take-while #(< % n)))

          next-p (->> p
                      (inc)
                      (iterate inc)
                      (remove marked)
                      (first))

          new-primes (conj primes p)]

      (if (>= next-p n)
        new-primes
        (recur next-p (into marked mults) new-primes)))))

; ----- Naive -----

(defn naive-prime? [n]
  (cond
    (< n 2) false
    (= n 2) true
    :else (->> n
               (Math/sqrt)
               (inc)
               (range 2)
               (some #(zero? (rem n %)))
               (not))))

(defn naive-primes [n]
  (->> n
       (range 2)
       (filterv naive-prime?)))
```

---

## Runtime Complexity:

I wrote up a testing function to automate timing with the help of Criterium for benchmarking:

```
(defn test-times [start-n end-n step-factor]
  (->> (iterate #(* step-factor %) start-n)
       (take-while #(< % end-n))
       (mapv (fn [n] [n (->> (c/quick-benchmark*
                               (fn [] (sieve-primes n))
                               nil)
                             (:mean)
                             (first))]))))
```

This tests how long it takes for various values of `n`, then packages the results in a vector of `[n time-taken]` pairs. Here are the results (times in seconds):

```
(test-times 1 1e7 2)
=>
[[1 2.3196602948749615E-7]
 [2 2.3105128053865377E-7]
 [4 1.42932799280724E-6]
 [8 5.63559279071997E-6]
 [16 1.2984918224299065E-5]
 [32 3.289705735278571E-5]
 [64 7.087895492662475E-5]
 [128 1.4285673446327686E-4]
 [256 2.923177758112095E-4]
 [512 6.273025793650794E-4]
 [1024 0.0012981272479166666]
 [2048 0.0025652252416666667]
 [4096 0.005141740791666667]
 [8192 0.01068772265]
 [16384 0.022486903166666666]
 [32768 0.05367695991666667]
 [65536 0.11212592816666668]
 [131072 0.23180363016666666]
 [262144 0.48056071016666674]
 [524288 1.1464995601666668]
 [1048576 2.8823068596666666]
 [2097152 6.4231157065]
 [4194304 15.808042165333335]
 [8388608 56.98961213533334]]
```

Plotting it out, it appears to be *roughly* `O(n^3)`. The time taken seems to *roughly* double every time `n` is doubled (`O(n)`) until n=524288, then it explodes. A custom Wolfram regression calculator gave a best fit with a cubic curve.

Comment: [ O  Gℎ, *please!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth) (i.e. compare the speeds at two size points at least, preferably three or more, to get better picture of what's going on there).

Comment: can it be that `(remove marked ps)` compares each `p` in `ps` against *all* elements in `marked`, out of order?

Comment: @WillNess A membership test of a set is near constant. This is also lazy, so it will only search enough to find the first result.

Comment: ok, thanks. what about the empirical orders of growth? it would give a good hint about the goings on.

Comment: @WillNess I haven't yet graphed the runtime of different n values. I can do that today. I did notice that it scaled better than the naive version though. It was only like 1.8x faster than the naive for n=1000, but ~2.2x faster for n=10000.

Comment: @WillNess I'm not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but I added a complexity bit at the end of the question in its own section.

Comment: there's no N^3 in your timings data. the exponents on each interval are calculated, according to the formula log(t2/t1) / log(n2/n1), as [0.0,2.63,1.98,1.20,1.34,1.11,1.01,1.03,1.1,1.05,0.98,1.00,1.06,1.07,1.26,1.06,1.05,1.05,1.25,1.33,1.16,1.30,1.85]. it seems compatible with the theoretical N log log N, up 500K, after which is starts slowing down, perhaps because it won't fit in the cache anymore. N^1.05 is perfectly fine and good for the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: @WillNess Ya, in retrospect N^3 doesn't make sense. The Wolfram calculator gave it the best match with cubic regression, but ya, it's not N^3. And thanks. I was hoping the sieve would be a significant improvement over the naive method, but I guess finding primes can only be optimized so far with simple methods.

Comment: why, the usual thing to do is to go by segments of approx. sqrt(top_n) size, with "segmented sieve". these segments are more likely to fit in cache.

Comment: @WillNess I saw that in the Wikipedia article; they have a whole section for segmented sieves. Maybe that'll need to be what I try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid the `cond` dispatch in `naïve-prime?`?

You could do `naive-prime?` this way:

```
(defn naive-prime? [n]
  (and
       (>= n 2)
       (->> n
            (inc)
            (Math/sqrt)
            (range 2)
            (not-any? #(zero? (rem n %))))))
```

This gets rid of the special cases `1` and `2`. The trick is to increment *before* applying `Math/sqrt`, so that the edge case `2` works correctly.

I've also elided the `not` into the `some` to produce `not-any?`.

> I'd mainly like recommendations for speeding this up.

Try

```
(defn sieve-primes [n]
  (loop [p 2 ; First prime
         marked #{} ; Found composites
         primes []]
    (let [mults (range (* p p) (inc n) p)
          next-p (->> p
                      (inc)
                      (iterate inc)
                      (remove marked)
                      (first))

          new-primes (conj primes p)]

      (if (>= (* next-p next-p) n)
        (into new-primes (remove marked (range next-p (inc n)))
```

There are a couple of changes here.

- Generate  `mults` as a `range`, starting at `(* p p)` - the first
  number that needs to be tested with prime factor `p`.
- Stop testing when the prime you would use, `next-p`, squared is
  bigger than the limit `n`.

I don't like the idea of building a massive set of composites. Better turn the algorithm inside out and test each number as it occurs against only the necessary prime factors. But that's a quite different algorithm.